# How to connect to MariaDB remotely

Tags: linux, debian, mariadb

I rarely use Linux as I'm a .Net developer and it is my first time using Debian, I have always used Ubuntu before on rare occasions.

I'm trying to connect to MariaDB. and I succeed locally both using localhost or host IP address, but remotely it fails.

What I have done so far (using instructions on the web):

1. Installed MariaDB and created a user with a password. and granted access on all databases:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'theusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   [image]
2. changed to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` on `mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

and can confirm it by the following result:

```
$ netstat -ant | grep 3306 returns

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

3. Firewall is not installed on the server.

4.MariaDB service is running and as I said I'm able to connect even with IP address from local computer.

the server is hosted on Amazon AWS.

Comment: Looks like this is NAT issue. Your database is behind AWS's NAT and has private IP; you can't connect to a private IP over the Internet. You need to forward port 3306 on the network gateway to your database server, and connect to the corresponding public IP. Or, setup VPN and go through it.

Comment: Or it's the AWS security group not allowing access